# How to increase the panning speed according to zooming level

Tags: c++, opengl

In the project I am working now panning in 3D scene seems not fast enough when the user zooms out.

When I check how panning is implemented I see Zoom level haven't taken into account.

I am thinking adding one more  multiplier called zoomLevel which get bigger when user gets far from the model.

Now after reading a bit I understood how I can create a ray from the scene coordinates. This [link](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html) help very much. My question is; I have a ray now from scene coordinates and also I have a pivot point in my model which I can use like reference. How can I create a zoomLevel factor from those?

My current idea is

- Find the closest and furthest points by adding z = -1 and z = 1 to
     scene cordinates and applying inverse projection and modelView
     matrix.
- Creating a ray from those two.
- Find the intersection of the ray and my pivot point. If point does not intersect than finding most closest point in the ray.

And creating a value like:

> zoomLevelFactor = (closestPointInTheRay.z() - closestPoint) /
>   (farPoint - closestPoint)

Does this makes sense? Do you have suggestions ?

Comment: Zoom level should be dependent on both camera position and target, not closest point. Imagine your world has a "mountain" right in the view line. The rest, "plane areas" would need a different zoom level. That's why I prefer playing with camera and target.

Comment: Zooming depens on the type or projection. For orthogonal it's just a scale transform in the mode (well, translate to your camera.xy, then scale, then translate back). For perspective is a matter of setting field of view and near and far planes.

Comment: @Ripi2  am using a perspective camera. Sorry can you please write your suggestion by steps I didn't understand what you meant. Do you advice me to change near and far planes?

Comment: I advice to get used with perspective concepts. Build a small app where you can choose field of view (fov), near and far planes. Run it varying just those values. You'll see some zoom efects. A great change comes from changing fov, but also notice perspective excessive efect depending on it.

Comment: @Ripi2 sorry for late response. Your saying of FOV and perspective concepts make me investigate yesterday.  I hope I understand better now. The thing is I am working in a legacy project which zoom level are adjusted by moving the camera further and closer in Z axis. So I hope I am not saying something wrong but it is implemented by manipulating Model-View matrix. As I understand now you are suggesting manipulating the projection matrix. Unfortunately project is very big and it is too late to change that.

Comment: Movig the camera in Z is like moving near and far planes, they are distances to camera. Moving camera in Z without updating near and far makes world move in the opposite direction. Updating near changes FOV.  If you need also panning it can be achieved by moving the camera (or the world in the opposite direction, you know) in XY, just a translation matrix.

Comment: @Ripl2 Thanks for still following up. Yes exactly translation is being appiled like that as well. But when the camera is very far from the pivot point panning is slow. I want to pan by some constant amount in both cases to be relative to the actual image on the screen

Comment: So you want to move in world space with a distance calculated in screen space. You need to unproject. That's another subject.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134904/discussion-between-kadir-erdem-demir-and-ripi2).